# Information about Section Index field (st_shndx) in Section SHT_DYNSYM & SHT_SYMTAB

Tags: arm, elf, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

Toolchain:
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 1 (build 49)

---

From ELF Portable Formats Specification, Version 1.1,

Section Index field (st_shndx) contains:
Every symbol table entry is ‘‘defined’’ in relation to some section; this member holds the relevant section header table index.

---

I am compiling a simple object (exports one global data & routine) to understand various fields of ELF

Source code (test.c):

```
__declspec(dllexport) int x21 = 0x100;
__declspec(dllexport) void bar21(void)
{
  x21++;
}
```

Build script used (build.bat)

```
armcc -c test.c
armlink --bpabi --dll -o test.dll test.o
fromelf -cdrsy -o test.txt test.dll
```

My query is about usage of st_shndx field of DYNSYM section & SYMTAB section.

Output file 
(Removed few sections to keep it short)

```
** Section #1 'ER_RO' (SHT_PROGBITS) [SHF_ALLOC + SHF_EXECINSTR]
    Size   : 24 bytes (alignment 4)
    Address: 0x00008000

    $a
    .text
    bar21
        0x00008000:    e59f000c    ....    LDR      r0,[pc,#12] ; [0x8014] = 0
        0x00008004:    e5901000    ....    LDR      r1,[r0,#0]
        0x00008008:    e2811001    ....    ADD      r1,r1,#1
        0x0000800c:    e5801000    ....    STR      r1,[r0,#0]
        0x00008010:    e12fff1e    ../.    BX       lr
    $d
        0x00008014:    00000000    ....    DCD    0

** Section #2 'ER_RW' (SHT_PROGBITS) [SHF_ALLOC + SHF_WRITE]
    Size   : 4 bytes (alignment 4)
    Address: 0x00000000

    0x000000:   00 01 00 00                                        ....


** Section #3 '.dynstr' (SHT_STRTAB)
    Size   : 32 bytes


** Section #4 '.dynsym' (SHT_DYNSYM)
    Size   : 80 bytes (alignment 4)
    String table #3 '.dynstr'
    Last local symbol no. 1

    Symbol table .dynsym (4 symbols, 1 local)

      #  Symbol Name                Value      Bind  Sec  Type  Vis  Size
    ========================================================================

      1  .data                      0x00000000   Lc    1  Sect  De   0x4
      2  shared_2.dll               0x00000000   Gb  Abs  Data  De 
      3  x21                        0x00000000   Gb    1  Data  Pr   0x4
      4  bar21                      0x00008000   Gb    2  Code  Pr   0x14


** Section #5 '.hash' (SHT_HASH)
    Size   : 40 bytes (alignment 4)
    Symbol table #4 '.dynsym'
<Section Truncated>


** Section #7 '.version' (SHT_GNU_versym)
    Size   : 10 bytes (alignment 4)
    Symbol table #4 '.dynsym'
<Section Truncated>    

** Section #8 '.version_d' (SHT_GNU_verdef)
    Size   : 56 bytes (alignment 4)
    String table #3 '.dynstr'
<Section Truncated>    

** Section #9 '.dynamic' (SHT_DYNAMIC)
    Size   : 120 bytes (alignment 4)
    String table #3 '.dynstr'
<Section Truncated>


** Section #10 '.debug_frame' (SHT_PROGBITS)
    Size   : 68 bytes


** Section #11 '.symtab' (SHT_SYMTAB)
    Size   : 176 bytes (alignment 4)
    String table #12 '.strtab'
    Last local symbol no. 6

    Symbol table .symtab (10 symbols, 6 local)

      #  Symbol Name                Value      Bind  Sec  Type  Vis  Size
    ========================================================================

      1  $a                         0x00008000   Lc    1   --   De 
      2  $d                         0x00008014   Lc    1   --   De 
      3  $d.realdata                0x00000000   Lc    2   --   De 
      4  shared_2.c                 0x00000000   Lc  Abs  File  De 
      5  .text                      0x00008000   Lc    1  Sect  De 
      6  .data                      0x00000000   Lc    2  Sect  De   0x4
      7  BuildAttributes$$ARM_ISAv4$S$PE$A:L22$X:L11$S22$IEEE1$~IW$USESV6$~STKCKD$USESV7$~SHL$OSPACE$EBA8$STANDARDLIB$REQ8$PRES8$EABIv2
                                    0x00000000   Gb  Abs   --   Hi 
      8  shared_2.dll               0x00000000   Gb  Abs  Data  De 
      9  x21                        0x00000000   Gb    2  Data  Pr   0x4
     10  bar21                      0x00008000   Gb    1  Code  Pr   0x14
```

Section 1 is Code area (bar21 routine is present here)

Section 2 is RW area (x21 variable is present here)

Now, if we see st_shndx (section index -- marked as "Sec" in output above) field in DYNSYM section & SYMTAB section for these two variables is different.

For Example: 
x21 in DYNSYM points to section 1 (code area) & in SYMTAB, it points to section 2 (RW area)

Can someone help me understand why? Or guide me to resource where I can get more information on this.

Regards,
Raju Udava